# relinking PHP after move from friends server to MAMP, fix in HTML or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I had a friend help me with some database work and he even made a basic html display of the functions...

I am now trying to move those functions to let us mess around with displays here at work.

The first drop down will load just fine, but the second and third ones are not loading.

I have the php database files loaded to the MySQL admin part in my MAMP server, but still can't get the code to reference it.

Is this something I can fix in HTML or PHP?

```html
 
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">
<html>
<head>
<title>dynaflex products testing</title>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload(form) //this js function fires when the 1st dropdown box is changed
{
var val=form.Makerid.options[form.Makerid.options.selectedIndex].value; //takes the "value" from the options listed in the form
self.location='dd3.php?id='+val ;//changes the location ofthe page (redirect) but it is taking the value from the above line
}
function reload3(form)//this function fires when u select the 2nd dropdown, it allows u to select from the 3rd box
{

var val=form.Makerid.options[form.Makerid.options.selectedIndex].value; //takes value from the 1st box
var val2=form.theModels.options[form.theModels.options.selectedIndex].value;  //takes value from the 2nd box
self.location='dd3.php?id=' + val + '&id3=' + val2 ;//this then redirects taking with it the values from above just like the last function but has 1 more varible
}
function redirect(form)//this form is the last box's action, can only be fired when u select the 3rd box
{
 self.location=form.theYears.options[form.theYears.options.selectedIndex].value; //redirects you to the url inside of the table at the url/value field just like the 1st function but differnt
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method=post name=f1 action='../../../Users/Marketing/Desktop/dd3ck.php'><select name='Makerid' onchange="reload(this.form)"><option value=''>Select one</option><option value=1>Peterbilt</option><option value=2>Kenworth</option><option value=3>Western Star</option><option value=4>Freightliner</option></select></form><br><br>
<a href=../../../Users/Marketing/Desktop/dd3.php>Reset and Try again</a>
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**dd3ck.php** *(PHP Code, as pasted into comment below gibberish's answer):*

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en"> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Multiple drop down list box from plus2net</title> 
    </head> 

    <body> 

    <?Php 
        $cat=$_POST['cat']; 
        $subcat=$_POST['subcat']; 
        $subcat3=$_POST['subcat3']; 
        echo " cat=$cat <br> subcat=$subcat <br> subcat3= $subcat3 "; 
    ?> 

    <br>
    <br> 
    <a href=dd3.php>Reset and Try again</a> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <center><a href='plus2net.com'; rel="nofollow">PHP SQL HTML free tutorials and scripts</a></center> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: html 3.2 - you've got to be kidding

Comment: graphic designer trying to learn here man...sorry.

Comment: Yeah, first thing you need here is some valid HTML before you worry about solving the php related stuff.

Comment: can anyone fix the code above for three dependable drop down menus? or is there a web link you can send me towards to help get that more valid?

Comment: @wisemanFTW See my two answers. *BTW, I am just reading a book* [***about a guy named Weizman***](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4032308-on-eagles-wings). *I don't think I've ever read a more interesting (and true) story.*

Comment: @gibberish ...that is an odd coincidence. Even more of one is in High School I used a Israeli Paratrooper messenger bag lol. I am trying the code you put in, and am starting to think that my usual technique of "bathe in fire" is not going to be how I learn PHP. I have relied on Adobe for far too long... "I didn't choose the Adobe Life, The Adobe Life chose me"

Comment: Please view some of the videos posted in my first answer. The time you spend is worthwhile. *I highly recommend the book - it's an unbelievable story. Also read about* [***his uncle***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Weizmann) *and* [***his brother-in-law***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Dayan) *But the best part of the story is his early years as a WWII fighter pilot. Some stories are too incredible to believe, if only they were not true.  PS - I am not Jewish...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted your PHP code into your original question.

The PHP code supplied does not reference your database at all.  It only receives three bits of data, called `cat`, and `subcat`, and `subcat3`, and then it attempts to print them onto the screen. However, that instruction is not written correctly.

It should be:

```
echo " cat=" .$cat. "<br> subcat=" .$subcat. "<br> subcat3=" .$subcat3;
```

Better yet, I would construct a variable and output the variable:

```
$out = 'cat: ' .$cat. '<br>';
$out .= 'subcat: ' .$subcat. '<br>';
$out .= 'subcat3: ' .$subcat3. '<br>';
echo $out;
```

In answer to your question:

> I Fixed It, Why Does It Not Work?

1. The page outputs the HTML as specified until it reaches the PHP BEGIN tag: `<?php`
2. It then reads the values posted into the webpage.
3. It then outputs to the screen (via the `echo` command) the labels, plus their values.

However, none of the values will print because the expected variable names are not sent to the `dd3ck.php` page!

Notice in your form:

```
<select name='Makerid'
```

That is the only HTML tag with a `name=` attribute. The name= attribute creates the **name** by which the value is posted into the `action=` file.

In the receiving PHP file (specified in the `action=` attribute), you can read that value like this:

```
<?php
    $myVarName = $_POST['Makerid'];
    echo 'I received: ' . $myVarName. '<br>';
```

Notice the label **Makerid**, in both the form and the (above) PHP snippet?

The `name=` attribute on any HTML element inside a form becomes the name that you must use inside the `$_POST['name_goes_here']` variable in the receiving PHP file.

Therefore, the instruction `$cat = $_POST['cat'];` etc will never work because there is no HTML element with `name="cat"`, or like `<select name="subcat3">`, or etc.

Comment: this...this right here...is going to help so much. Will check back in a bit as I start to insert this in.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

First, try to structure your code so that it is more readable. (Note the change to the `<script>` tag. Also, you are not quoting your "strings" -- you can mostly use single and double quotes interchangeably, but don't 'mix" them - "be" 'consistent')

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>dynaflex products testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function reload(form){
                //this js function fires when the 1st dropdown box is changed
                var val=form.Makerid.options[form.Makerid.options.selectedIndex].value; //takes the "value" from the options listed in the form
                self.location='dd3.php?id='+val ;//changes the location ofthe page (redirect) but it is taking the value from the above line
            }
            function reload3(form){
                //this function fires when u select the 2nd dropdown, it allows u to select from the 3rd box
                var val=form.Makerid.options[form.Makerid.options.selectedIndex].value; //takes value from the 1st box
                var val2=form.theModels.options[form.theModels.options.selectedIndex].value;  //takes value from the 2nd box
                self.location='dd3.php?id=' + val + '&id3=' + val2 ;//this then redirects taking with it the values from above just like the last function but has 1 more varible
            }
            function redirect(form){
                //this form is the last box's action, can only be fired when u select the 3rd box
                self.location=form.theYears.options[form.theYears.options.selectedIndex].value; //redirects you to the url inside of the table at the url/value field just like the 1st function but differnt
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" name="f1" action='../../../Users/Marketing/Desktop/dd3ck.php'>
            <select name='Makerid' onchange="reload(this.form)">
                <option value=''>Select one</option>
                <option value='1'>Peterbilt</option>
                <option value='2'>Kenworth</option>
                <option value='3'>Western Star</option>
                <option value='4'>Freightliner</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <br><br>
        <a href="../../../Users/Marketing/Desktop/dd3.php">Reset and Try again</a>
        <br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Next, there is no PHP in here.

You need to show us the content of this file: `../../../Users/Marketing/Desktop/dd3ck.php`

---

Finally, here are some great FREE video tutorials for learning this stuff:

https://phpacademy.org/videos/php-and-mysql-with-mysqli

https://phpacademy.org/videos/oop-loginregister-system

https://phpacademy.org/videos

https://buckysroom.org/videos.php

Comment: thanks gibberish, ill take some screenshots of the the database and be back in 5

Comment: ok having trouble getting the code back into the comments...
`
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">

<html>

<head>
<title>Multiple drop down list box from plus2net</title>
</head>

<body>
<?Php

$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$subcat=$_POST['subcat'];
$subcat3=$_POST['subcat3'];

echo " cat=$cat <br> subcat=$subcat <br> subcat3= $subcat3 ";

?>
<br><br>
<a href=dd3.php>Reset and Try again</a>
<br><br>
<center><a href='http://www.plus2net.com' rel="nofollow">PHP SQL HTML free tutorials and scripts</a></center> 
</body>

</html>